How can I handle the Privileged Instruction Exception on Windows?
I have written a code that checks presence of VMWare hypervisor by testing the in instruction. I can't use __try/__except keywords since I build for MinGW.
static char inside_vm;

static LONG WINAPI IsInsideVMWareExceptionHandler(
    struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *ExceptionInfo) {
  ExceptionInfo->ContextRecord->Rip += 1; // Skip 'in' instruction.
  return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
}

int IsInsideVMWareVM(int vmware_v2) {
  inside_vm = TRUE;

  void *handler = AddVectoredExceptionHandler(
      1, IsInsideVMWareExceptionHandler);

  asm(
      "pushq %%rdx\n"
      "pushq %%rcx\n"
      "pushq %%rbx\n"

      "movl $0x564D5868,  %%eax\n" // 'VMXh' magic value
      "movl $0, %%ebx\n"           // any value but not the magic value
      "movl $10, %%ecx\n"          // get VMWare version
      "movl $0x5658, %%edx\n"      // VMWare hypervisor port
      "in %%dx, %%eax\n"           // read port,
                                   // on return EAX returns the VERSION
      "cmp $0x564D5868, %%ebx\n"   // is it a reply from VMWare?
      "setz %0\n"                  // set return value

      "popq %%rbx\n"
      "popq %%rcx\n"
      "popq %%rdx\n"
      : "=a"(inside_vm)
    );

  RemoveVectoredExceptionHandler(handler);

  return inside_vm;
}

The problem is that AddVectoredExceptionHandler() doesn't necessary intercept the Privileged instruction exception (0xc0000096) when running on a real machine. My standalone executable works fine, but when I integrate the code into another application I get crashes due to the unhandled exception above. Could you suggest me what might be a cause of the problem?
UPDATE: It looks like the problem is related to Golang (I embed the code above into a Golang app) which uses vectored exception handling (VEH) rather than structured exception handling (SEH).

Is clang an available alternative? It apparently does support SEH.

No, unfortunately it's not an option.

AddVectoredExceptionHandler() doesn't necessary intercept the Privileged instruction exception (0xc0000096) - this is of course false

So why doesn't the code work when I embed it into Golang app (exits with 0xc0000096 exception), but works perfectly when built standalone?

@ababo ALL exceptions, which passed to user mode, first go throughout VEH. ALL

But how is that possible? SEH is a native path for Windows hardware exception, isn’t it? And I pass non zero to AddVectoredExceptionHandler(), so why doesn’t it arrive to my handler first?

SEH called after VEH and if VEH not handled exception. if VEH not called - the SEH of course will be not called too. and i not familiar with your concrete binary. what here called or not called
